# Access Filter with subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a search box on one form that finds records by OrderID (ex 305321) on a checkout and ordering form and a second that I just added to a form to look up flooring products that searches the FLID value (ex FLID00005) the second however will only return a new record even when the data that I am searching for exists and when I use the enter functionality on it it asks for a parameter value which if I enter the same value that is in the search box it runs properly.

The code for the Orders search form:

```
    Private Sub cmdFindbyOID_Click()
    If IsNull([FindByOIDSearchBox]) Then
        MsgBox "You must Enter a Order ID", vbInformation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Filter = "(([Orders In Progress Query].OrderID = " & FindByOIDSearchBox & "))"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.[Orders All Details Subform].Requery
End Sub

Private Sub FindByOIDSearchBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        cmdFindByOID.SetFocus
    If IsNull([FindByOIDSearchBox]) Then
        MsgBox "You must Enter a Order ID", vbInformation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Filter = "(([Orders In Progress Query].OrderID = " & FindByOIDSearchBox & "))"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.[Orders All Details Subform].Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

The code for the flooring products form:

```
Private Sub cmdFindbyFLID_Click()
    If IsNull([findByFLIDSearchBox]) Then
        MsgBox "You must Enter a Flooring ID", vbInformation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Filter = "(([Flooring Products Query].FLID = " & findByFLIDSearchBox & "))"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub FindByFLIDSearchBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        cmdFindbyFLID.SetFocus
    If IsNull([findByFLIDSearchBox]) Then
        MsgBox "You must Enter a Flooring ID", vbInformation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Filter = "(([Flooring Products Query].FLID = " & findByFLIDSearchBox & "))"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLID contains characters.  Therefore, your reference needs to be inside a single quote.

```
Me.Filter = "(([Flooring Products Query].FLID = '" & findByFLIDSearchBox & "'))"
```

Comment: Thank you I figured it was something dreadfully simple I was missing